# why "==" working differently for integer and strings reference?

Tags: java, equality

May I know how `==` works here?

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = new String("str");
        String s2 = new String("str");
        System.err.println("why it,s "+String.valueOf(s1==s2));
        int i1 = new Integer(10);
        int i2 = new Integer(10);
        System.err.println("why it,s "+String.valueOf(i1==i2));
    }
```

}

When I am comparing references of two different `String` with the same values, then `==` says that they are not equal, but when I am comparing references of two integers with the same values, then `==` says that they are equal. Why is it so?

Comment: You should always use `s1.equals(s2)` with java

[See here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: no i just wanna ask why i1==i2 is true while s1==s2 is false

Comment: `i1` and `i2` are not references, they are primitives (because of the type `int` and [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)) and so have the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, a more meaningful compare would be

```
public class App{
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String s1 = new String("str");
   String s2 = new String("str");
    System.err.println("why it,s "+String.valueOf(s1==s2));
    Integer i1 = new Integer(10);
    Integer i2 = new Integer(10);
    System.err.println("why it,s "+String.valueOf(i1==i2));
}   
}
```

`int` is primitive, and == will just compare the value.  `Integer` is an object, and == for objects is only true if it points to the same place in memory, otherwise it will be false.  For primitives (int, boolean, etc...) == will test the value.

`int i = Integer(10)` is really `int i = (Integer(10)).intValue()`, java just does it automagically.

Edited to add more explanation:

Java has 2 types of types.  Primitive types and Class types.  A primitive type is just the value of the type:  an int primitive type is just that, and int.  There are not methods or anything, it just is an int.

If you say `int a = 4`, a is a primitive variable that points to a memory address that contains an int.  That's it.

A Class type is a java object, so Integer is a class type.  It *represents* an integer value, so `Integer a = new Integer(4)` would create an integer object, and a would point to a memory location that contains the *object that new... created*.

What's different?

Good question.  In the latter example (new Integer(4)) this is an integer *and some other stuff*, stuff like a `toString()` method and some other stuff.

So, a recap:

A primitive is a value stored in memory somewhere.
A class is an object stored in memory somewhere, and in the case of Integer it represents an int but it has some other stuff associated with it (i.e. the `toString() method).

Now, == is a test for equivalency.  So `int == int` checks to see if the primitive value is the same, since that is the only information that a primitive type has.

== for objects *does* mean something.  Since an object points to a more than just a 4 or 8 or -1, the == only returns true if the object variables point *to the same place in memory*.  If it does not, then you get false.

So:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
Integer k = new Integer(1)
Integer l = new Integer(1)
Integer m = k;
Integer n = new Integer(k)

i == j -> true
k == l -> false
k == k -> true
k == l -> true
n == m -> false
n.intValue() == m.intValue() -> true (intValue returns a primitive type)
```

Now, .equals is a test to see if two objects are equal, which means different things for different objects.

For an Integer, a.equals(b) is true if the intValue()s are the same for a and b.  However, a == b is true if a and b point at *the same object in memory*

Now, thing about an object that has 2 integers in it (like an x,y coordinate).

Comment: but, why System.err.println() method showing false for both?

Comment: @G4uKu3 because they are different objects and so have different reference values.

Comment: @G4uKu3 If I remember correctly, whenever you use `new`, you are guaranteed to get back a new object that is not equal (using `==`) with any other object in the JVM.

Comment: This sure was a lot of effort invested into a question that's a duplicate.

Comment: lol, that sure was a good comment and really adds to the discussion.